# jQuery coundown of days not working in Edge

Tags: jquery

I have written a small function to display the number of days left between a date and today. It's working in all browsers except Edge, where its returning `NaN`.

I originally thought it could be due to `Date.parse`, but this doesn't seem to be an issue in Edge, elsewhere.  Can anyone see what the issue could be?

```js
function countdown() {
  var endTime = new Date("23 May 2020 13:00 GMT+01:00");
  endTime = (Date.parse(endTime) / 1000);

  var now = new Date();
  now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

  var timeLeft = endTime - now;
  var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400);
  $(".to-go span").html(days);
};
countdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="to-go"><span></span></div>
```

Here is a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yg6weqs4/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in Edge is because it cannot parse the `"23 May 2020 13:00 GMT+01:00"` string to a date. I'd suggest changing this to an ISO8601 formatted date string, eg:

```
var endTime = new Date("2020-05-23T13:00:00+01:00");
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/be2j9xzh/)